# How do I cancel / abort a rollback in infinidb?

Tags: mysql, infinidb

When I start infinidb, I am getting the following error message, making it impossible for the service to start. In the log file, it says there is a problem with the rollback. Is there a way to abort the rollback so I can start the service again? I am ok with losing some data.

```
Starting Calpont InfiniDB Database Platform: ....... DONE

Warning! The DBRM is currently in Read-Only mode!
Updates will not propagate!

Starting Calpont InfiniDB MySQL:
Starting MySQL
. *
Validate InfiniDB System Catalog:
Validation Succesfully Completed
Perform Functionality test:
InfiniDB Logging check: DONE
Platform Process check: ERROR: Problem with InfiniDB process DMLProc, should be a single version running

***Stopping InfiniDB to allow the process problem to be resolved.

Shutting down Calpont InfiniDB MySQL:
Shutting down MySQL
... *
Shutting down Calpont InfiniDB Database Platform:
```

/var/log/Calpont/crit.log

```
DMLProc[4292]: 41.458706 |0|0|0| C 20 CAL0002: DMLProc failed to start due to :  problem with rollback.  Version buffer file  does not exists.
```

I already tried removing the files in `/usr/local/Calpont/data1/systemFiles/dataTransaction` but it still won't start.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I was able to solve it.

While the service is starting:

`# service infinidb start`

In another ssh session go to `/usr/local/Calpont/bin` and look for the transaction ID causing the problem:

`# ./rollback -p`

Once you find out, immediately run the rollback command with the transaction id that you see:

`./rollback -r 64536`

It will respond with OK and the service started successfully this time. I had to do this twice because my first attempt was probably not able to rollback the transaction on time.